# Modificar onclick de hijo

Tags: javascript

Tengo

```
<li id="anterior" class="page-item disabled tooltip">
     <a onclick = "" class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        <span class="tooltiptext"> Anterior</span>
     </a>
</li>
```

y quiero modificar onclick de a desde js. ¿Cómo accedo a él?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que modificarlo como cualquier otro atributo de etiqueta, a través de la función `setAttribute`.

```js
(function() {
   const enlace = document.querySelector('#anterior a')
   
   enlace.setAttribute('onclick', 'nuevoValor')
})()
```

```html
<li id="anterior" class="page-item disabled tooltip">
  <a onclick="" class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    <span class="tooltiptext"> Anterior</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

**Referencia:** [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

Answer (score 0):

Tambien puedes agrear en la seccion de script un eventListener para el boton y cuando quieras modificarlo, borrarlo y luego añadir otro

```
<li id="anterior" class="page-item disabled tooltip">
     <a id="button" onclick = "" class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        <span class="tooltiptext"> Anterior</span>
     </a>
</li>


const elem = document.getElementById("button");
elem.addEventListener("click", functionquequierasponer);

function cambiarEventListener(){
     const elem = document.getElementById("button");
     elem.removeEventListener("click", funcionquepusisteantes);
     elem.addEventListener("click", nuevafuncion);
}
```

Obviamente no se llama a la funcion cambiarEventListener porque no tengo tu código completo, pero llamarías a esa función en el momento o sitio donde quieras que se cambie